# segmentation fault while appending a linked-list

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I am trying to append a node at the end of the linked list and I am getting a segmentation fault. I am not able to figure out where is my mistake. Any Help and suggestions would be appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
            int data;
            struct node *next;
    }*head;
    void append(int x)
    {
            struct node *temp1,*right;
            temp1=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp1->data=x;
            right=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            right=head;
            while(right->next != NULL )
            right=right->next;
            right->next=temp1;
            right=temp1;
            right->next=NULL;
    }                                                                             
    void print(){
            struct node *temp=head;
            printf("List is: ");
            while( temp!=NULL )
            {
                    printf(" %d",temp->data);
                    temp=temp->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

    int main(){
            struct node *temp;
            int n,i,x;
            head=NULL;//empty list;

            printf("how many numbers?\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);

            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                    printf("\nEnter the number\n");
                    scanf("%d",&x)
                    append(x);
                    print();
            }
    }
```

Comment: `head=NULL;`, and never gets written to after this.. it does read from it and this may be the segfault. run it in your debugger and post also the output from the backtrace

Comment: If you haven't stepped through your code with a debugger you haven't invested enough effort.

Comment: http://ideone.com/xX0m26

Comment: Thanks!I got my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `append` you dereference a pointer which points to `NULL`-

```
right=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
right=head;
while(right->next != NULL )
....
```

As `head` points to `NULL` and then you point to `head` by `right` , so basically by `right->next` you dereference a pointer to `NULL` . That's why you maybe getting a seg fault .

And also you allocate memory to `right` and loose reference to it after making it to point `head` causing memory leak (*avoid such things*).

This can be avoided by pointing `right` after allocating memory by `head` -

```
head=right;
```

Comment: thanks! I got my mistake!

Comment: @prajwalsanket Glad that helped :-)